# What sort of view controller approach is best for an iPhone iOS app using multiple window views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface

I am interested in creating an app that starts with a menu which may possibly contain an options view, then steps from the menu view to a data-item selection view, then to a configuration view, and finally a result view that displays progress or changes. I want to have this process be repeatable like a loop, and have the user be able to jump backwards to a previous view if necessary. Jumping from view to view would of course be a user input / output with a button or something. FYI, I am using Xcode 5.1.1.

What would be the best approach to this? What kind of view controller is going to do the trick? I have heard a lot about navigation controllers, tables, etc.. but am having a hard time figuring out what to use in my case.

Below is a state-diagram similar to what I would like to do...

[image: App-FlowChart-Concept]

Comment: Didn't you post this question earlier? I've seen this same image earlier, but it also looks like that question was deleted.. I remember there was at least 1 answer that mentioned using a `UIPageViewController`

Comment: Yes. I needed to revise my post. I am new to this site too.

Comment: Don't repost questions. If you have an issue with a question, revise it as needed. This one will get closed too since it is as off-topic as the original. Please click the help link above and read about asking questions here.

Comment: Like I said... I am new to this site. But thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)  should work great as your root view controller. It automatically includes a back button, and you can use the popToRootViewController method to return to the root of the navigation controller. You can set up a navigation controller as your root view controller from the applicationDidFinishLaunching method using this code.

```
MainMenuViewController *mainMenuViewController = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainMenuViewController;
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

For more information take a look at apples UINavigationController programming guide https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Each of your other screens may use different types of view controllers depending on their specific needs. If you need to display a list of items, definitely look into a UITableView. Apple's documentation for a UITableViewController can be found here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html